# JavaScript to get text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, ajax-upload

I have JavaScript of ajax uploader as below;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var qwerty = $('#qwerty').val();

$('#demo1').ajaxupload({
  url:'upload.php',
  remotePath: qwerty,
  maxConnections:1,
  finish:function(files)
  {
    alert('uploaded');
  },

});
});
```

`var qwerty` is the value of a text input having default `value=""`. The field is blank when page loads. The text inside is set as the upload directory of the uploader. But it return null even if I enter some text inside. When I reload the page, the text I enter previously remain there and this time, the text is taken and passed into variable. Again if I change the text, the data passed is the text which remained in the input field and not the one I entered now. How can I always pass the current value of input field into the variable?

Comment: You really want to remove the `,` in `},` after your `finish` function. Otherwise it will cause various problems in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your ajaxupload when document is ready. After changes in your input nothing has happened, because your ajaxupload uses previous version of your input value.
You can reinitialize ajaxupload after changing textbox value.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   //Initializing when document is ready
   InitializeAjaxUpload();

    $("#qwerty").change(function () {
   //Initializing after input value changes
     InitializeAjaxUpload();
    });
    });

function InitializeAjaxUpload()
{
$('#demo1').ajaxupload({
              url:'upload.php',
              remotePath: $('#qwerty').val(),
              maxConnections:1,
              finish:function(files)
              {
                alert('uploaded');
              }

    });
}
```

I didn't tested this, but you need something like this. Try it :)

Comment: it is creating another event of uploader... :P

Comment: So, by clicking to the button it want to upload more than one files? Is Chuck Norris understand right?

Comment: the function ajaxupload initializes already on pageload. no need to do that anymore..

Comment: Need is to change remotePath value of ajaxUpload :)

Comment: In my written example it will every time create new ajaxupload instance with new input value. Where am I wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9262/discussion-between-chuck-norris-and-blasteralfred)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){` means when page loads and all document elements ready. And it called once after page load. At that time your input value is empty so it doesnt matter you type after. You need event listener to get data from input text.

Comment: When page loads it try to upload. You need to clearify what you want to do

Comment: I want to update the variable qwerty live... The variable should carry input data in real time...